Are endpoints supposed to disappear after deleting a service?
I am studying kubernetes by reading the textbook Kubernetes in Action. I'm on the chapter talking about Services and Endpoints.
I noticed that if I create a service and endpoints separately ,then I delete the service, then the endpoints are also deleted.  Even if I use the --cascade=orphanoption in the delete command, the endpoints still are not orphaned.  Why am I experiencing this result?  How come I can't retain the endpoints?  Here's the experiment I tried:
This is my test.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: p1
  - port: 91
    name: p2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  # must match the service name
  name: external-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.244.0.110
    - ip: 10.244.0.111
    - ip: 10.244.0.112
    ports:
    - port: 80
      name: p1
    - port: 91
      name: p2

Then I ran these commands:
kubectl apply -f test.yml;
kubectl get endpoints;  # i confirmed endpoints do exist
kubectl delete svc external-service --cascade=orphan;
kubectl get endpoints; # the endpoints are gone


The Endpoints object is tightly coupled to the Service object with the same name. When you create a Service, Kubernetes automatically creates and manages the corresponding Endpoints object to represent the set of IPs and ports backing the Service.
and in your example, you have created the Endpoint with same name as the Service, when you run kubectl delete service, kubernetes interprets it as a signal to delete the associated endpoints as well.
Now for the second question: the --cascade=orphan didn't work, because it work when there's ownerReferences in the objects, but the endpoints doesn't have ownerReferences pointed to the service. the deletion happens because of the kubernetes internal logic for cleaning up the endpoints which are related to the services.
for the last question:
if you want to retain a specific endpoint, just create it with a different name than the service name. now, after deleting the service, kubernetes will not delete the endpoints, as they do not share the same name anymore.
